# Is there a way to navigate to a specific directory if it's not in the active directory in Cygwin?

Tags: windows

"I am not able to turn back more than once and if I try to take away a folder from the stack it replies 'directory stack empty'.">

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you looking for `cd /specific/path`, `cd /` or `cd ..`? Or something with `popd`/`pushd`? Please [edit] and clarify. An example can help.

Comment: I'm looking to see if it's possible to go to a path that isn't inside of the active directory, as in my Cygwin it is fixed to an unkwown directory to me and I'm trying to get out of it so I can access my C: drive.

Comment: By "active directory" you mean the current working directory of the shell, right? I believe you can enter `C:` by `cd /cygdrive/c`. I still don't know what it has to do with `directory stack empty`. Please do not add explanations in comments. [Edit] the question and improve it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer by experimenting. I've just started learning how to use Cygwin and realised `cd ..` was a thing and thought `cd -` would work.